# Distingue-t-on les voyelles de "il pèche" et "une pêche" au Québec ?

Tags: prononciation, québec, phonème

Est-ce que les Québécois prononcent *il pèche* comme *une pêche* [pɛ:ʃ] ou bien comme *sèche* [sɛʃ]?

Dans quelle référence est-ce que je peux trouver des réponses à ce genre de question? J'ai vérifié dans le dictionnaire Usito, mais il ne donne pas la prononciation des formes conjuguées.

Edit. Merci à livresque pour sa réponse documentée. L'article de Laurent Santerre cité dans sa réponse contient en effet une liste d'une vingtaine de mots avec leur prononciation en [ɛ:] ou [ɛ]. Parmi ces mots-là, il y en a trois qui ne sont pas donnés dans Usito. Premièrement, en plus de *pèche*, il y a une autre forme conjuguée, à savoir un enfant qui *tète* [tɛt], par opposition à un mal de tête [tɛ:t], et deuxièmement un nom propre, *Grèce*, qui se prononce [grɛ:s] tout comme *graisse*. Je trouve l'extrait suivant particulièrement intéressant:

> Le français québécois n'a donc pas gardé tous les archaïsmes du français de la colonisation; mais il a développé, ou plutôt il est en train de développer ses propres longues, alignées sur les longues étymologiques. Par exemple, on avait une paire minimale *pêche* [pɜʃ] / *pèche* [pɛʃ]; dans *pêche* la voyelle est une longue par nature étymologique, dans *pèche*, la voyelle est une brève étymologique (de *peccare*). J'ai fait des sondages auprès des étudiants et de quelques Montréalais, et il se révèle qu'à Montréal, tout au moins, *pèche* s'aligne sur *pêche*, *Grèce* sur *graisse*, etc. Tandis qu'en France l'assimilation générale des /ɛ/ se fait à l'avantage du /ɛ/ bref (*une tête bien faite* [yn tɛt bjɛ̃ fɛt]), à Montréal l'assimilation ou l'alignement se fait actuellement dans certains cas, rares malgré tout, à l'avantage de la longue. De même, certaines longues par nature, perdues dans certains dialectes de France, ont tendance à reparaître dans la région de Montréal. Exemple : tandis que dans le Bas Saint-Laurent on dit *arrête* [arɛt] comme en France, à Montréal on entend surtout [arɜt]. On dit même *cesse* [sɜs] qui avait une brève par nature.

> On trouve donc dans le français québécois des longues par nature, dont la plupart sont d'origine étymologique, et d'autres longues qui sont de nouvelles longues analogiques, alignées sur les autres. Elles ont les mêmes caractéristiques et les mêmes tendances à la diphtongaison.

Maintenant pour que la réponse soit parfaite il faudrait trouver une liste plus exhaustive qui permette de suppléer aux données manquantes d'Usito. Je trouve que le Littré me renseigne bien en général sur l'opposition entre [ɛ] et [ɛ:], mais il s'agit justement d'avoir une référence qui comprenne aussi les nouvelles longues non-étymologiques comme dans *pèche*, <s>*Grèce*</s> et *cesse* qui n'ont jamais été longues en France.

Comment: Est-ce que la voyelle de Grèce était courte dans le parler des premiers colons ? On retrouve beaucoup de prononciations longues de ce mot en Europe également, et dont j'ai toujours supposé que la source était les termes savants d'origine grecque en ης comme Thalès, Périclès, Xerxès et compagnie.

Comment: Plus anecdotiquement, c'est intéressant de comparer ça à la situation belge, où Grèce est universellement /grɛ:s/ alors que graisse est un des rares mots avec la graphie "ai" en syllabe fermée qui ait une voyelle courte (avec faite, naisse et connaisse). De même pèche est /pɛːʃ/ mais pêche (le fruit comme l'activité) /pɛʃ/. Ici la source semble être le le substrat roman, qui avait généralement /ɛʃ/ là où le français avait /ɛːʃ/.

Comment: Les mots avec des cognats romans sont restés courts (pêche, bêche, rêche), ceux plus rares, savants ou religieux (crèche, pèche, calèche, etc) ont acquis une voyelle longue par hypercorrection.

Comment: @Eauquidort Vous avez raison de soulever la question au sujet du mot *Grèce*. Selon un dictionnaire français de 1950 que j'ai pu consulter, il aurait eu une voyelle longue en France. La recherche est évidemment compliquée un peu par le fait qu'il s'agit d'un nom propre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En voilà une chez Wikipédia qui montre la différence des diphtongues [phonologique de Québec](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology) : pêcher [pɛɪ̯ʃe].  Les mots qui s'écrivent en *ê* ou *è* peuvent montrer les syllabes ouverts ou fermés qui  peuvent se prononcer en [ɛɪ̯] jusqu'à [ei̯], [æɪ̯] et [aɪ̯].  On peut écouter la prononciation du nom *une [pêche](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%AAche)* comme [paɪ̯ʃ].

> The phonemes /ɛ/ and /ɛː/ are distinct. In open syllables, /ɛː/ is
> diphthongized to [ɛɪ̯] (pêcher is pronounced [pɛɪ̯ʃe]), but it is
> pronounced [ɛː] before /ʁ/ (mairie is pronounced [mɛːʁi]), it is
> pronounced [ɛː] before /v/ (trêve 'truce' [tʁ̥ɛːv]), and in closed
> syllables, it is diphthongized to [ɛɪ̯],[4] [ei̯], [æɪ̯] or [aɪ̯]
> (tête 'head' [tɛɪ̯t], [tei̯t], [tæɪ̯t] ⓘ or [taɪ̯t] ⓘ); on
> Radio-Canada, speakers pronounce [ɛɪ̯] in both open syllables and
> closed syllables.

[Deux E et deux A phonologiques en français québécois : étude phonologique](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/cl/1974-n4-cl3106/800031ar.pdf) ne voit pas de distinction entre une *pêche* et il *pèche*

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse! J'ai modifié ma question en conséquence.

Comment: Ben c'est un début de réponse après ça, elle est bien posée, ta question.  Toi aussi, tu as le droit de répondre à la question comme tu as fait pas mal de recherche ! Bienvenue encore sur French Language SE.